# KeyError as a direct cause of exception when i try to insert values where there is None

Tags: python, pandas

Goal: Whenever there is `None`, the values of `three` should be inserted

```
df3.loc[df3['wp'].isnull(), 'wp'] = df3['three']
```

works for most of the data but somewhere (i cannot determine where) it throws

```
KeyError: 'wp'
```

Question: How can i try:except or work around this error in order to keep the code running until all data has been processed?

Comment: You've got a bug. You need to fix the bug.

Comment: Maybe `df3` doesn't actually have a `wp` column at all, but that's a wild guess. We don't have enough information to be able to diagnose anything or determine the correct course of action, beyond "fix the bug".

Comment: NB. trying to solve this "issue" with a try/except is likely a bad idea (like putting you head in the sand to avoid seeing a real-life problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not a recommended solution but it's enough to check if 'wp' it's a key:

```
if 'wp' in df3:
    df3.loc[df3['wp'].isnull(), 'wp'] = df3['three']
```

or with try/except:

```
try:
    df3.loc[df3['wp'].isnull(), 'wp'] = df3['three']
except KeyError as e:
    print(e)
```

By the way I really suggest you to debug and understand where the problem is!